# Не работает приложение на другом компьютере на python.Файл exe

Tags: python, pyqt5

Всем здрасьте, написал приложение с графическим интерфейсом(PyQt5) на Python. В exe конвертировал через pyinstaller не одним файлом. Вот как я привязывал интерфейс к коду:

```
    def start(self):  # start the app
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/project/train.ui')  # главное окно
        self.ui.show()
```

Вот так ставил иконку приложения

```
        myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
        QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
        self.ui.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/project/img/logo.ico'))
```

Отправил другу для теста, и вот что он получил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок и может вам нужна еще какая-то информация, извините если что, заранее спасибо

Comment: Ты используешь полный путь до файла, которого не будет на других компьютерах.

Comment: Я рекомендую вам сконвертировать `train.ui` в `train.py`. 
А для изображений использовать файл ресурсов. 
Вопросы как это сделать - многократно обсуждались на SO.

Comment: А можно как-то без преобразования решить проблему ?

Comment: Андрей, проблему можно решить по разному, я рекомендую вам опыт лучших практиков.